# SAS hardrive 600GB 10k is not detecting in my linux server

Tags: hard-disk

I have inserted one new 600 GB HDD to my Linux server. Green light is glowing but in my Oracle Enterprise Linux 5.5 OS it is not showing after executing the command below:

```
fdisk -l
grep -H . /sys/block/sd*/device/model
```

Comment: Is the HDD formatted correctly? ... I know that in MS Windows, that you add a new HDD, and if it is formatted incorrectly, it won't be detected.

Comment: Please check if anything popped up on dmesg when you inserted the drive. Also, I assume you're using hot-swap capable hardware, right?

Comment: @Kevdog777 `fdisk -l` will show the drive even if it doesn't have a partition table (it will tell you it couldn't find a partition table).

Comment: Check the BIOS setup of your box, whether BIOS detects the disk or not.

Answer (score 1):

If this is how-swappable hardware, you still need to issue a scsi-rescan. You can do this from the command line [directly](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-rescan-a-scsi-bus-without-rebooting) ,or have a [script](https://github.com/pld-linux/rescan-scsi-bus/blob/master/rescan-scsi-bus.sh) do it for you.